# How to configure mysql for large tables with billions of rows and hundreds of gigabytes

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database, I have some large tables that are used for reporting purpose. The biggest one currently has more than 4 billions rows, datas size is over 300GB and index is about 250GB. Average row size is 84B. The table itself consist of 20 number columns and 1 date colums. Among these, 10 columns are foreign keys and the others are metrics. Because it's about reporting and date is a key component of about every requests, this table partitionned by date using the following : PARTITION BY HASH ( YEAR(date) * 12 + MONTH(date))
PARTITIONS 96
Thoses tables use MyISAM engine over InnoDB. I've considered migrating to InnoDB but for SELECT requests it happened to be a nightmare in terms of time to get a result (hundreds of times more than the same table using MyISAM).

My initial assumption seeing this kind of partition (I did not created it) was that running a request using where date = now() would make that MySQL only reads the partition matching the hash for this date and not all the partitions (acting like some master index), and that write requests would lock only the impacted partitions. However, it seems not which is infortunate in terms of performance.

So I would like to have some inputs about the best way to use MySQL for such big tables ? 
I know partition is always claimed to be better, but considering lock issue and index, I wondered if performance would not be better splitting my table into multiple sub tables and then UNION JOIN or using a VIEW for SELECT requests ?

```
    CREATE TABLE `report_table` (
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `key_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `key_2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_5` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_6` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_7` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_8` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `key_9` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_5` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_6` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `metric_7` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `metric_8` float(27,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
    `metric_9` float(27,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
    `metric_10` float(27,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
    `metric_11` float(27,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`,`key_1`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    /*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( YEAR(date) * 12 + MONTH(date))
    PARTITIONS 96 */
```

Comment: Your innodb slowness was probably a very small innodb_buffer_pool size. Partitions are usually when you want to drop a partition quickly. More details on the exact queries run would help provide correct indexes for this table. `EXPLAIN {query}` shows what is needed to get the results and which index are being used. https://dba.stackexchange.com is a good forum for these purely database questions.

Comment: @danblack innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G over 64G on the server.
I would'n say queries are the issue, explain show they use indexes as expected, it's the migration from myisam to innodb that introduce slowness in select queries.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use present trending technologies like Apache Spark/Apache Flink for your processing. Since your data is huge these processing engines gives the best performance ever. Here you can control on your partitions also. Please have a look on Apache Spark which is as simple as Hadoop.Its proved that Spark is 10 to 100X times faster than Hadoop specially designed to deal with BIGDATA.

Comment: Thanks, but switching to another technologie might have software implications so before considering such an option I would like to optimize the existing mysql first. I saw mariadb has some interesting engines (aria to replace myisam, tokudb to big data), what about these engines ?